# API GatewayでURLに日本語を含んだリクエストが文字化けしてしまう

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, rest, aws-api-gateway

API GatewayとLambdaを利用して、RESTfulなapiを開発しているのですが、URLに日本語を含んだリクエストが文字化けしてしまいます。
CloudWatchのログを見ると、API Gatewayの時点で文字化けしているようです。

例えば、GETで"/list/q/画像"にアクセスすると、CloudWatchの方では"GET /list/q/ç»å"というアクセスログが残っています。

EC2でapacheを使ってデプロイした時は大丈夫だったのですが、API GatewayとLambdaにデプロイしたらこうなってしまいました。
解決策をお教えいただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: **_GETで"/list/q/画像"にアクセス_** とありますが、リクエストは`/list/q/%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F`と正しくパーセントエスケープされているのでしょうか? API GatewayもLambdaも詳しいことは知りませんが、URLに(本来は不正な)日本語バイト列が含まれているとそのようなログ出力になることがあります。

Comment: 正しくエスケープしても同様のレスポンスが返ってきます・・

Comment: 元のご質問のどこにもレスポンスが出てこないのに「同様のレスポンス」とだけ言われてもなんのことやらわからないのですが…。確認ですが、「EC2でapacheを使ってデプロイした時」には、きちんとエスケープしていたのでしょうか、していなかったのでしょうか? どんな環境で何をしたらどうだった、という事柄をできるだけ詳しく上げていただかないと、API GatewayやLambdaに詳しい方でも回答するのが難しいだろうと思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/165864